# Oneshot BLE Advertisement

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

You can set the interval of Bluetooth Low Energy advertisement (20ms is the shortest).
Is there a way to advert one time only?
I tried stopping advertisement just after starting the advertisement but sometimes two advertisements are done.

I'm using bleno node.js library.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing even in the HCI protocol. You can maybe set a large advertising interval, start and then stop within this time.